# Visual basic throw "Format of the Initialization" error when connecting to DB

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, vba

I need to upload an excel file, read its content and insert it to my DB.

I always get this error :

> Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification
>   starting at index 186.

I found some solutions (although most of them use `C#`), i tried to apply them but no success :

```
connString = ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & path & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;"")")
```

I also tried :

```
connString = ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & path & ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;)")
```

But none of them work. This is the path :

```
"C:\Users\tama\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\uploader\uploader\File\Plan TEST.xlsx"
```

And i have make sure that the `path` is correct and the file format is `xlsx` so i use version `12.0`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var pathExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
    var connectionString = string.Empty;
    if (pathExtension == ".xls")
    {
      connString = string.Format(@"PProvider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0}; Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES\";", yourPath)
    }
    if (pathExtension == ".xlsx")
    {
      connString = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES\";", yourPath)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try it when i go back to code. Probably tomorrow.